# Difference between private and privileged method

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose i have a class like this.

```
function kevin(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.methodKevin = function(){
        console.log(this.name);
   };
   var kevin = function(){
        console.log(this.name); 
   }
   function newKevin(){
        console.log(this.name);
   }
}
```

1. What is the difference between them in javascript?.
2. Is my class perfect, can i have a function expression inside my
   constructor?

Comment: Did you come up with the name "priviledge method"? I think it's Brillant.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: Typo... anyway... its privileged Method.

Comment: I've never heard of that one before either.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen The idea of a `privileged method` in JavaScript was popularised by Douglas Crockford: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how they are called, and maybe confusing to talk about since there are two functions named: `kevin`.

1. `methodKevin` will be bound to the window object unless called by `new kevin`, in whichcase it be bound to the top level `kevin` function object. `this.name` will be as expected only work if called by a function instantiated with `new`.
2. `var kevin` is function scoped to the parent `kevin` funciton, so that it may never be  called outside that function. It is private in that sense. `this.name` will work, but `name` alone will suffice.
3. same as 2